# Why is this samurai able to chop pellet gun bullets

Tags: speed

In this episode of Discovery Channel, Isao Machii, Modern-Day Samurai, Cuts a speeding Pellet in half.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qzhs1Z8Rwnk

Now they are in awe, and a professor admits his speed is faster than known reaction speeds, or even cognitive speed.

But there's no explenation as to how this Samurai practitioner got this fast. No inside story.. anyone?
What's his spiritual explanation?

Comment: -1. There's no such things as samurai any more since [the Charter Oath promulgated at the enthronement of Emperor Meiji of Japan on 7 April 1868](http://history.stackexchange.com/a/162/103). There is nothing either spiritual or magical about training your body to draw a sword towards a moving target. All you need is practice and enough takes till you get slice a small pellet.

Comment: Acording to the lady professor it's not possible because of limits in perception and reaction speed? Also curious how i should name the practitioner?

Comment: Samurai is a political title dating back to feudal japan.  You wouldn't call a practitioner of German Longsword a knight.  So, though people emulate the samurai ethos as a part of their commitment to Japanese martial arts, they are not samurai.  Haven't watched the video, but I assume he's doing some flavor of kenjutsu, thus he would be called a kenjutsu-ka.  The alternative is that he's doing iaido / iaijutsu (two names for the same art.

Comment: Maybe this question would do better on the physics stack exchange?

Comment: Good point about political title. But regarding exchange, i don't imagine Japanese doctrine wrt swordsmanship is about physics, more likely something with spirit realm?

Comment: **There is nothing mystical in that video.** It could easily be a simple case of clever editing: you are never shown how many times they tried. They could have tried as many times as needed until they got the needed result.

Comment: Sardathrion is 100% correct here.  There is nothing at all mystical about using a sword to destroy a tiny object.  I have watched the video now, and the only thing "spiritual" going on here is the swordsman's intense focus.  Other than that, it's all training, training, training.  Some people get into martial arts because they think there's a mystical secret.  Those people quickly leave when they find how painful/boring/mundane the training actually is.

Comment: Ok, tv probably wants to make a nice story. But this Japanese man does hold multuple Guinis Book records: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isao_Machii  Regarding mundane.. i agree. but in the east there's much more to 'martial' than in the west, so i don't exclude spirit stuff per-se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This man is probably utilising Getsumei No Michi (Moonlit path). It sounds much more mystical than it actually is though. It is simply a mental technique for heightening your senses naturally (as opposed to utilising psychotropic drugs). It's not a spiritual exercise so much as an exercise in "daydreaming" until you reach a state of heightened sensitivity.

Ever felt like time slowed down during a scary event like a car crash? Getsumei No Michi allows you to enter this state by choice.

The technique is roughly speaking the opposite of meditation. Meditation has you focusing on one thing, Getsumei No Michi has you focusing on nothing, and letting your mind wander (kind of like daydreaming).